# Debian 6 Synaptic Package Monitor checkboxes are acting like no software is installed

Tags: apt, debian-squeeze, synaptic

I was playing with package manager on my debian squeeze, was trying to install php 5.4 instead of php 5.3 and now it acts like everything is removed, I dont see any green "checkboxes" on already installed software, all the checkboxes are clean and it acts like nothing is installed. It looks like I completely removed all the data about already installed packages.. Is there a way back? How to restore it?

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer and [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you're able.

Comment: Will do, Sir! Just have to wait 6-8 hours to answer my Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved! For others with the same problem:**

```
cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```